# Exclude service contract namespace in WCF response

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working with the most frustrating third paty tool in memory.  Current problem:

It can't read the WSDL from my web service if I don't supply a namespace (I'm guessing it's tied to how the WSDL breaks out/references xsd files) in the ServiceContract attribute, BUT if I do supply a namespace, it cannot handle the returned XML because it flunks out when there's an xmlns attribute in the root of the response.

I think it's a longshot but is there a way to tell WCF to NOT use a namespace in the resulting Http
Response element???

Thanks.

**Edit Adding Example**

What I get right now (when supplying a namespace in the ServiceContract attribute):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<HttpPostResponse xmlns="http://mynamespace.com">
  <HttpPostResult>
    <STAT xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RESPONSE _SEQUENCE_ID="1" _VERSION="1.0" _DATE="10/04/2012 12:03:21">
        <STATUS _TYPE="FAILURE" _PRODUCT_CODE="1">
          <ERROR _CODE="9002" _DESC="Bad code.  Bad code!"/>
        </STATUS>
      </RESPONSE>
    </STAT>
  </HttpPostResult>
</HttpPostResponse>
```

What I'd LIKE is the same only without the xmlns attribute in the root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<HttpPostResponse>
...
```

I'm "flying blind" as I have essentially no control over the third party app so am trying to find workarounds to conform to what it will understand.

Comment: How are you trying to read the WSDL? What do you mean by "using a namespace in the HTTP response element"? Can you add some examples of what you have and what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks, Carlos.  Edited.  The WSDL is read just by supplying the URL?wsdl to the third party app.  I've noticed that how it breaks up into supporting, separate XSD files is notably different between when I supply a namespace in the ServiceContract and when I don't.  I suspect this is why the app can handle one version (with NS) and not the other.

Comment: Just to be clear, the example what you have isn't WSDL, it looks like a normal response. WSDL (Web Service Description Language) describes the service. What you want is to remove the namespace from the *response*, right?

Comment: Where is the `http://mynamespace.com` coming from? This isn't a default namespace used by WCF, so you should be able to search for it in your code and change that, no?

Comment: How are you generating the code? Are you rolling your own, importing through VS's "Add Service Reference" or svcutil, or ... ?

Comment: Thanks guys.  Yes, Carlos, I added what I would like the response to wind up as, not the WSDL.  mynamespace.com is an internal namespace (we're building out SOA internally).  In the response it's coming from my [ServiceContract(Namespace="mynamespace.com")] attribute.  However, if I drop the namespace from the attribute the updated WSDL is not consumable by the tool.  @Mike, the service is a self-rolled one.  FYI this has been demoted from sticking point to curiousity as we're heading away from the 3rd party tool for these functions due to such issues.